# What is best practice to remove static noise?

Tags: noise, speech-recognition, speech-processing, signal-synthesis

What is best practice/algorithms  to remove static noise from speech ? static noise aka Stationary Signal/static noise due to

- 1.humming sound due to of telephonic line/channel,
- 2.moving Vehicle,or due to
- 3.constant noise of fan or other nearby instrument .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard method to remove stationary noise is [spectral subtraction](http://www.cslu.ogi.edu/nsel/wan_manuscript/node10.html), where
the magnitudes of the short-time Fourier transform of the noisy signal are modified based on an SNR estimate in the respective frequency bin. The algorithm by Ephraim and Malah (see [this paper](http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/~bacry/MVA/EM.pdf)) and its variants are used a lot. Note that the basic principle of spectral subtraction is very simple, but that a lot of engineering is necessary to make it sound good. A very important ingredient is the noise/SNR-estimator.

Comment: Can you please suggest an open source implementation of this method. or the implementation that you usually use. @Matt L.

Comment: @MAS: When I was working on spectral subtraction I used a proprietary software of a company I worked for at that time. I never used any open source implementation. But I'm sure there must be several out there.