# What is spectral subtraction?

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, noise, background-subtraction

I have to write some simple examples in Matlab which use spectral subtraction. These examples will be included in a paper to help a friend understand spectral subtraction. But I don't know where to start with spectral subtraction ?
Please, explain the technique and maybe give me some tips for what can I do with this method in Matlab. Some snippets of code would be very useful for me as I am not an expert in Matlab.

Comment: Please search this site and the internet. A LOT has been written about spectral subtraction and it's not useful to repeat everything. As a start, have a look at [this answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17317/what-is-best-practice-to-remove-static-noise/17318#17318).